# Rest API call with Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I faced a problem while trying to access a basic rest api I've created. I get the famous 404 error when i type   http://localhost:8080/projectName/rest/hello , as you can see in the code snippet below, I expect a "Hello world" String as response. 
I think I am missing some extra configuration there..

Any advice  would be appreciated

```
@Controller
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@RequestMapping("/rest")

public class EntityController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello" , method=RequestMethod.GET , produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE) 
    public @ResponseBody String hello() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try without produces?

Comment: Please post your Spring MVC configuration and deployment descriptor, and describe how your application is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to expose the "application name", try to just make a GET request for:

`http://localhost:8080/rest/hello`

Comment: I agree this sounds like it could be the problem. By default the `@RequestMapping` would point to the root of the url.

Comment: Still got the same error :/ , Is it necessary to use some kind of rest implementation like apache cxf ... ?

Comment: @Mustafa The `/projectName` wouldn't be set by Spring MVC, it would be set by the servlet container. It's completely unrelated to the controller. This answer is a guess at best and makes assumptions that aren't clearly stated nor based on anything in the question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how can I configure the servlet container to point to my project ?

Answer (score -1):

You should use RestController on your class to enable your service to return a json body. 
To Consume the service, you need to add the application name after the host, and then the path of your controller and method name, just like this

```
@RestController
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class EntityController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello" , method=RequestMethod.GET ,produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE) 
        public @ResponseBody String hello() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

After that, your path to the REST operation would look like

> http://localhost:8080/app-name/rest/hello

Hope it helps

Comment: How does this explain a 404?